# How to integrate Facebook login in FuelPHP website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, fuelphp

I am trying to integrate Facebook login with my website using FuelPHP. I am a newbie in FuelPHP. I did what is said here [fuelphp-social-package](https://github.com/gkwelding/FuelPHP-Social-Package)

When trying to test it I am getting following error.

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
Cannot use object of type Facebook as array
/home/everycite/facebook/src/base_facebook.php @ line 226
```

and in line 226 is follwing code of `base_facebook`:

```
public function __construct($config) {
    $this->setAppId($config['appId']);
    ...
}
```

`$config['appId']` is showing correct api id of my app. I am not getting it. How to solve this?

Comment: Did you try Sentry social? It can be integrated in FuelPHP: https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1#fuelphp-1.x and https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry-social/2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fuelphp have package for managing login by social media (facebook, google, linkedin,twitter) here the link
http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/auth/opauth/intro.html